# How to convert array string to JSON value?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This string is received from database:

"[{\"country_code\":\"IN\",\"gdpr_fields\":{\"policy\":\"yes\",\"profiling\":\"na\",\"age\":\"yes\",\"subscription\":\"na\"}}]"

I have been trying to convert this string to a JSON value but it always ends up throwing an error

```
undefined:1
[{\"country_code\":\"IN\",\"gdpr_fields\":{\"policy\":\"yes\",\"profiling\":\"na\",\"age\":\"yes\",\"subscription\":\"na\"}}]
  ^
Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 2
```

Is there a way to convert this string to JSON using javascript?

Expected Result:

```
[{"country_code":"IN","gdpr_fields":{"policy":"yes","profiling":"na","age":"yes","subscription":"na"}}]
```

Comment: _I have been trying to convert this string to a JSON value_ ... How? It looks like you are parsing JSON instead of stringifying it.

Comment: Why do you have a string like that in the first place? Can't you fix the issue with whatever's creating it?

Comment: is that string coming from database ? looks like you have double time json stringified it.

Comment: also putting code in question would help others better understand your situation.

Comment: This string is coming from the database.

Comment: Indeed, it's a perfectly fine JSON string and can be parsed as-is. Show your actual code.

Comment: @ChrisG No, the string is not valid JSON. The backslashes are actual characters in the string. You can see it in the error message. They're not escape symbols.

Comment: Didn't you post a fiddle where you plugged the string directly into `JSON.parse`? Why did you remove that comment? Pasting OP's string as-is into JS source makes the backslashes mask the double quotes inside the double quote delimited string. It can be used as-is.

Comment: @ChrisG Because it took a moment until I understood the error message and were able to reproduce the problem. When the backend sends this string you can't parse it. You can simulate it with https://jsfiddle.net/4sv3famd/

Comment: @jabaa Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/ydsuczvr/ Until we understand how exactly OP is receiving and parsing the string, posting answers to this is pointless.

Comment: @ChrisG _"This string is received from database:"_ describes exactly where the string comes from. That means the backslashes are actual characters in the database. That's the actual value in the database. The error message `Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 2` describes it, too. The backslash is an actual character / token, not an escape symbol.

Comment: @jabaa As my fiddle shows, JSON.parse() can deal with actual backslash characters. I understood the error message the first time I saw this question. However OP's question doesn't contain enough information to give an appropriate answer, and if they store malformed JSON in their DB in the first place, providing a workaround to parse it is not a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @ChrisG I showed you a fiddle that proves that `JSON.parse` can't handle actual backslashes: https://jsfiddle.net/egm5vhtu/ Often databases are connected to many systems and it's not possible to fix all systems at once. A workaround is sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `\"` with `"` with `replaceAll` or `replace` with a regex (for older browsers/engines):

```js
const invalidJson = '[{\\"country_code\\":\\"IN\\",\\"gdpr_fields\\":{\\"policy\\":\\"yes\\",\\"profiling\\":\\"na\\",\\"age\\":\\"yes\\",\\"subscription\\":\\"na\\"}}]';

try {
  JSON.parse(invalidJson);
} catch(err) {
  console.log('Parse error');
}
const json = invalidJson.replaceAll('\\"', '\"');
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

```js
const invalidJson = '[{\\"country_code\\":\\"IN\\",\\"gdpr_fields\\":{\\"policy\\":\\"yes\\",\\"profiling\\":\\"na\\",\\"age\\":\\"yes\\",\\"subscription\\":\\"na\\"}}]';

try {
  JSON.parse(invalidJson);
} catch(err) {
  console.log('Parse error');
}
const json = invalidJson.replace(/\\"/g, '\"');
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var temp = "[{\"country_code\":\"IN\",\"gdpr_fields\":{\"policy\":\"yes\",\"profiling\":\"na\",\"age\":\"yes\",\"subscription\":\"na\"}}]";   


temp = JSON.parse(temp);

console.log(temp);
```

Please use something like this, it is working for me.

Comment: Hey, @user12551649 use this, it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

This could be only possible by first cleaning the string

```
jsonArr = "[{\\\"country_code\\\":\\\"IN\\\",\\\"gdpr_fields\\\":{\\\"policy\\\":\\\"yes\\\",\\\"profiling\\\":\\\"na\\\",\\\"age\\\":\\\"yes\\\",\\\"subscription\\\":\\\"na\\\"}}]".split("\\").join("")
```

and then

```
JSON.parse(jsonArr)
```